# html input field issue

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i'm new to html and this is probably a stupid mistake but i cant spot it. Whenever i select a input field, the cursor always jumps to the first input box. I'm guessing i missed an ending statement somewhere but i cant spot it...

```
<form method = "POST" action="changeCourse.php";>

<label for="newModule">Module:<label>
<input type="text" name="newModule" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['modules'];?>"/>

<label for="newCode">Code:</label>
<input type="text" name="newCode" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['codes'];?>"/>

<label for="newLesson">Lesson Type</label>
<select name="newLesson" id="newLesson">
                    <OPTION SELECTED><?php echo $_REQUEST['lesson_types'];?></option>
                    <option label="newLesson">Lecture</option>
                    <option label="newLesson">Tutorial</option>
</select>

<label for="newCredit">Credit:</label>
<input type="text" name="newCredit" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['credits'];?>"/>


<label for="newLevel">Level</label>
<select name="newLevel" id="newLevel">
                    <OPTION SELECTED><?php echo $_REQUEST['levels'];?></option>
                    <option label="newLevel">4</option>
                    <option label="newLevel">5</option>
                    <option label="newLevel">6</option>
</select>

<label for="newCore">Core:</label>
<input type="text" name="newCore" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['cores'];?>"/>

<label for="newLab">Lab Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="newLab" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['labs'];?>"/>

<label for="facilities">Lab Facilities</label>
                  <select name="facilities" id="day">
                    <OPTION SELECTED><?php echo $_REQUEST['facilities'];?></option>>
                    <option label="facilities">Full(MS Office, Programming Packages, Adobe Packages)</option>
                    <option label="facilities">Partial(MS Office, Adobe Packages)</option>
                    <option label="facilities">Simple(MS Office)</option>
</select>

<label for="newTeacher">Teacher:</label>
<input type="text" name="newTeachers" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['teachers'];?>"/>

<label for="newDay">Day</label>
                  <select name="newDay" id="day">
                    <OPTION SELECTED><?php echo $_REQUEST['days'];?></option>
                    <option label="newDay">Monday</option>
                    <option label="newDay">Tuesday</option>
                    <option label="newDay">Wednesday</option>
                    <option label="newDay">Thursday</option>
                    <option label="newDay">Friday</option>
</select>

<label for="newTime">Time:</label>
<input type="text" name="newTime" input value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['times'];?>"/>


<label for="newComment">Additional Comments:</label>
<textarea style="resize: none;" cols="30" rows="3" name="newComment"> hello </textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Update Record" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ids'];?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the reason but you have a bunch of `input value`'s and it should only be `value` drop the `input`

Comment: Oh i think i found your answer.. Your first label is `<label for="newModule">Module:<label>` and it should end with `</label>` not `<label>` .. notice the `/` before the `<`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your HTML. Open up your page in the browser, show the HTML source code and copy and paste it as direct input to an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Fix all mentioned issues, and try again.

Do you still have the problem once your HTML is fixed?